# why does the jquery selector work from right to left?

Tags: jquery

Recently i was reading about how the jquery selector works.
it appears it looks at everything from right to left
for example `$('.myclass span')` will look in the dom for all the span tags then it will check if myclass is a parent class for any of those tags.

I also understood that css does the exact opposite. i understand that both ways can be highly inefficient.

I am wondering if there is a special reason for this.

here are 2 sources for my claim:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-think-right-to-left-with-jquery--net-18052
https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/jquery-angularjs-comparison-migration-walkthrough

Answer (score 1):

This basically the way you perceive the selector You quoted the [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and as per your understanding  it "*will look in the dom for all the span tags then it will check if myclass is a parent class for any of those*" But the jQuery documents say

> Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

```
$('.myclass span')
```

Here we have .myclass as Ancestor and span as descendant. In the example you, it seems more logical for me that Ancestor should come first in the selector as it is added to DOM before its descendants are added in the DOM. Its appears in the html before its descendants.

As the internal working of jQuery finds the element in reverse order but that is totally abstract from the jQuery programmer. For programmer the selector in reverse order is contrary to what he see in the html.

Comment: i am not tying to ask how it works. i am trying to ask why it works that way.

Comment: In the example you quoted, it seems more logical for me that Ancestor should come first in the selector as it is added to DOM before its descendants are added in the DOM.

Comment: lets say i have $('#menu a') you think its more logical for it to find all the a tags in the dom then find all the parents that have a menu id parent?

Comment: i would think it should first find the #menu id and look for the a tags under it

Comment: The internal implementation for finding the element by jQuery is less important for deciding the syntax of selector. As what the consumer of selector (jquery developer) see is html not the algorithm jQuery is using.

Comment: as you can see in the artical https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/jquery-angularjs-comparison-migration-walkthrough it can be the difference of 6 seconds.